Can't seem to only get latest date's data in PowerBI
I have a table that has dates as columns and then data for each date eg

I want to only get data from the most recent date.
I thought if I used something like
Data Required = calculate(
sum('table'[values]),
filter('table',max('table'[date])
)

That would give me what I would expect but it's giving me all dates summed together.
How can I just get data from the latest date?
It currently feels like it's just ignoring the max date filter.
Thanks

Found it!
Found the answer helpfully in this post How to get the value at the latest date, where values are not null?
I still don't know my original idea didn't work but this was the solution:
Latest Value = 
    VAR last_date = max('Table'[Date])
    RETURN
    CALCULATE( SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Value]),'Table'[Date] = last_date)

